# Approval Workflow for SP2013 foundation using Workflow Manager

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, 2007

We know SharePoint 2013 foundation does not have "Approval workflow" from out of the box. If I install and configure Workflow Manager 1.0.

Can I create "Approval workflow" for SharePoint 2013 using Designer?

Now we are planning to move from Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I have lots for approval workflow in MOSS those needs to be move as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say this that SharePoint 2013 Foundation doesn't support Workflow Manager it uses the same workflow engine that SharePoint 2010 Foundation uses and does not include an Approval Workflow. The only answer that I can suggest is that you either recreate your own custom Approval Workflow or that you purchase the version of SharePoint 2013 that includes those workflows and supports the new Workflow Engine.

Comment: What you mean own custom workflow? writing code as feature or with designer?

Comment: Me personally I have went both routes and I prefer for simple workflows even multi-level approval workflows to use SharePoint Designer. I used a rule list to dynamically power my approval workflows up to 6 levels. If you need more capabilities you can always use .NET and design a feature

Answer (score 2):

Workflow Manager will not work with SharePoint Foundation 2013.

[The SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not supported in SharePoint Foundation 2013.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15).aspx)

You can't create workflow in designer for 2013 platform. check this for [supported features in SPF 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)

You can use SharePoint Designer 2013 and have to select the platform "SharePoint 2010 Workflow".
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219638%28office.15%29

Therefore "old style" meant WF based on Framework 3.5, "new" WF 4 incl. Azure ...

Comment: Anything code based approval workflow available as feature to activate?

Comment: you can check the codeplex.com if some body write something over their

Comment: check this one http://sharepointwf.codeplex.com/

Comment: oops. There is nothing to download.